# How to merge repeating query to one function in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, merge

I have these repeating queries in my script using jQuery:

```
    if($(".splitname:contains('Kompakt')").length > 0) {
        var komText = $(".splitname:contains('Kompakt')");
        $.each(komText, function() {
            $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/Kompakt/g,"Kompakt<br />"));
        })
    }

    if($(".splitname:contains('System')").length > 0) {
        var sysText = $(".splitname:contains('System')");
        $.each(sysText, function() {
            $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/System/g,"System<br />"));
        })
    }
```

...and 4 similar if-conditions.

I want to merge them in a function like this:

```
function splitCat(splitVar, splitName) {
    var split = $(".splitname:contains('splitName')");
    ...
    ...
}
```

I have tried different ways but it does not work (i get no errors but the function itself is not firing).

Comment: `$(".splitname:contains(" + splitName + ")");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function splitCat(splitName) {
    var els = $('.splitname:contains("' + splitName + '")');
    var regex = new RegExp(splitName, 'g');
    els.html(function(html){
        return $(this).text().replace(regex, splitName + '<br />');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
$(".splitname:contains('splitName')");
```

with

```
$(".splitname:contains(" + splitName + ")");



function splitCat(splitVar, splitName) {
           var split = $(".splitname:contains(" + splitName + ")");
           ...
           ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
function splitCat(splitVar, splitName) {
    if($(".splitname:contains(" + splitName + ")").length > 0) {
        var komText = $(".splitname:contains(" + splitName + ")");
        $.each(komText, function() {
            $(this).html($(this).text().replace(splitName, splitName + "<br />"));
        })
    }
}
```

Not sure what `splitVar` was supposed to be in this case.